# Afinal, "AMANHECER" é sempre verbo intransitivo?

Tags: gramática, verbos, sintaxe, transitividade-verbal, verbos-intransitivos

**Contexto da dúvida:** Peguei uma lista de exercícios sobre análise sintática online para estudar, pois vou prestar vestibular muito em breve, e essa oração em particular me deixou um tanto confusa, principalmente porque só consegui achar explicações - divergentes entre si - de casos similares

**Dúvida:** Na oração *"Amanheceu um dia muito agradável"* esse verbo é intransitivo, sendo então o sujeito da oração *"um dia muito agradável"*, ou o sujeito é inexistente como normalmente se assume em casos de fenômenos naturais, e nesse caso o verbo deve ser transitivo direto e com *"um dia muito agradável"* como complemento verbal, como diz o gabarito da lista?

Já não sei mais o que pensar...

Comment: amanhecer é intransitivo OU copulativo (tipo parecer, ser ou estar). Por exemplo, Ele amanheceu no sofá. Não acho que possa ser transitivo.

Answer (score 1):

O comentário de @Lambie está correto e dá uma dica boa para responder à sua pergunta: o verbo *amanhecer* somente pode ser intransitivo ou *de ligação* ([também chamado às vezes de *copulativo* ou *predicativo*](https://www.infopedia.pt/apoio/artigos/$copulativo)).

Para ser franco, fiquei em dúvida, no seu exemplo, se o sujeito da oração seria "*um dia muito agradável*" , ou se seria um sujeito oculto com um predicato sendo ligado por *verbo de ligação*; no entanto, segundo definições dos dicionários [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/amanhecer) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/amanhecer), *amanhecer* define-se como *verbo de ligação* quando tem o seguinte significado

> Estar em determinado lugar ou situação pela manhã

Em seu exemplo, "*Amanheceu um dia muito agradável*", claramente não há "alguém" que "amanheceu um dia agradável", e "um dia" (modificado por adjetivo) não é um lugar nem uma situação; portanto:

**RESPOSTA CURTA**: "um dia" (modificado por adjetivo) é o sujeito da oração, e "amanhecer" é um verbo intransitivo.